# Uncertainity in java != with !equals

Tags: java, string, exception, equals

I wrote a small program to read a csv file...I used buffered reader for that...
My code looks like this:

```
package files;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import bk.bk;

public class QwithLinkedList{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        FileReader f=new FileReader("G:/bk.csv");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(f);
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=(null)){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Above is perfect code but my question is that I'm getting an exception with this code :

```
package files;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import bk.bk;

public class QwithLinkedList{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        FileReader f=new FileReader("G:/bk.csv");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(f);
        String line;
        while(!(line=br.readLine()).equals(null)){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The output for the above code is this :

```
a1
bk
abc
def
ghi
jkl
bharath
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at files.QwithLinkedList.main(QwithLinkedList.java:14)
```

Someone please explain why it is giving an exception with the above code.
Moreover if(a!=b) and !a.equals(b) are't they same ?

Comment: Because you end up with `null.equals(...)` but `null` doesn't have any methods, including `equals`.

Comment: `a != b` and `!a.equals(b)` are _not_ the same. The first compares _object identity_ whereas the second simply invokes the (possibly overridden) [`public boolean equals(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) on the `a` instance.

Comment: @bharath: The difference between `==` and `equals()` (or `!=`and `!equals()`) is vital for java programming. Please make sure you understand the difference and what @jensgram writes, otherwise you'll run into very hard to find bugs.

Comment: @pshemo thanks man...now I got to know the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking for null, always use `==` or `!=`. Using `equals` will always become a `NullPointerException` if what you are checking is null.

The difference between `==` and `equals` is that the former checks whether or not both sides points to the same address in memory, while the latter checks for object equality.

Comment: Thanks man now I got the difference

Answer (score 0):

When checking for a null value, never use the .equals() since it might return a NullPointerException as in your case.

Comment: You just confirmed OP problem but didn't explain its cause. Question is "**why** it is giving an exception with the above code" (emphasis mine)